# Find camera right and up vectors

Tags: 3d

I have this camera setup:

```
Pos(px,py,pz)
LookAt(lx,ly,lz)
Up(ux,uy,uz)
```

I need to find the cameras *right* and *up* vectors, a way to find them with an explanation would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you already have a camera pos (p), target (l) and up (u) vectors. To calculate right, find the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of (p - l) and (u  - p).

This will give you a vector orthogonal to both, the "right" vector.

Comment: thanks, from what im reading there's no guarantee that the specified up vector is perpendicular to the direction the camera is looking at.

Comment: Yes - for a given position and a look-at point there are infinite "up" vectors. You have to choose one that is appropriate. For example, the "falling over dead" effect in Quake is implemented by changing the "up" vector of the camera.

Comment: You can choose an arbitrary correct "up" (say [0, 1, 0]) and considering you never need to rotate around the direction of view, keep it constant. This (http://www.gameprogrammer.net/delphi3dArchive/viewing.htm) old article is where I learnt some of these concepts from.